# Card Memory/Matching Game: losing click handler after classes added and removed

Tags: javascript

Okay, this is my very first post on Stack. Here is my issue. I am in the early stages of creating a Card Matching Memory Game for my final project at Udacity. I click on a card and classes of "open" and "show" are added to the card. Another class, "inactivated", is added to deactivate the click handler using css pointer-events set to ‘none’ (so a card cannot be clicked twice). I click the second card and the same sequence happens. No problem at this point. I am only concerned about no matches right now. If there is no match, the classes, “open”, “show” and “inactivated” are removed.  At that point, it appears that I can click any card in the deck but when I click on a card, nothing happens.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/SteveAB/buvt42ke/1/

```
// event listeners

classname = document.getElementsByClassName('card');

for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    classname[i].addEventListener('click', displayCard);
    classname[i].addEventListener('click', checkMatch);

};

  displayCard = function() {

        if ((guessOne !== 0) && (guessTwo <= 1)) {

            // alert('GuessOne is ' + guessOne);

            this.classList.toggle('open');
            this.classList.toggle('show');
            this.classList.toggle('inactivated');

        }

        if (guessTwo === 1) {

            // alert('GuessTwo is ' + guessTwo);

        inactivate();

        }

        guessTwo++;

    };



 checkMatch = function() {

        openCards.push(this);
        let len = openCards.length;

        if (len === 2) {

            //alert("move counter - two clicks is a move");

                if (openCards[0].id === openCards[1].id) {

                    alert("calling Match function");

                    match();

                } else {

                    //alert("calling notMatch function");

                    notMatch();
                };

            };

        };
 function inactivate() {

        Array.prototype.filter.call(cards, (function (card) {

            if (card.classList.contains('inactivated')) {

                return;

            } else {

                card.classList.add('inactivated');

                // console.log(card);
            }

        }));
    };

    function reactivate() {

        Array.prototype.filter.call(cards, (function (card) {

            if (card.classList.contains('match')) {
                return;

            } else {

            card.classList.remove('inactivated');           

            }

        }));
    };

 function notMatch() {

        setTimeout(function(){
            openCards[0].classList.remove('open', 'show');
            openCards[1].classList.remove('open', 'show');
            openCards = [];
            reactivate();            

        }, 1800);



    };
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you can provide us a jsFiddle or a working snippet, where you include the html also. In StackOverflow you can edit your question and use the toolbar button with this symbol `<>` to add a snippet of working code

Comment: Don't link fiddle in the comments, add it directly to the question. But I also recommend to post the code as a snippet here in SO, like I said in the first comment. (If I have some free time I wll try to help, for now I can't)

Comment: Thanks Calvin.  Sorry about putting the fiddle in the comment.  I will edit and update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `guessOne` and `guessTwo` never get reset.  If you add the line `console.log(guessOne, guessTwo` to the top of `displayCard` and watch the console when you click you'll see:

```
0 0
1 0
1 1
1 2
1 3
```